# Consulta de caracteres especiais no SQL

Tags: sql, select, caracteres

Preciso fazer uma consulta em uma tabela de e-mails, e necessito que retorne apenas os e-mails que possuem caracteres especiais.

Pode me ajudar com o script, tentei usar esse código:

```
Select * from tabela Where Coluna LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9, ]%'
```

mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Informe o SGBD , algumas síntaxes mudam.

Comment: Se seu banco for MySQL, `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna REGEXP '[^A-Za-z0-9, ]'`. Vale lembrar que, possivelmente, a consulta trará todos os e-mails que também possuírem o `@`.

Comment: A pergunta foi fechada por não informar o SGDB; detalhe importante e que LIKE provavelmente nao suporta RegEx, ao menos na maioria dos SGDBs. Para continuarmos dentro da [finalidade do site](/help) é importante você [edit] a pergunta e fornecer o [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Comment: olá, esta [publicação](https://danizavtz.com.br/consulta-de-caracteres-especiais-em-uma-coluna-string-que-possui-enderecos-de-email/) pode ajudar.